# Setting Rmd directory

Tags: r, directory, r-markdown

I'm new to R. I usually work my projects in a setting characterized by a directory in which I assign datasets, code and graphics specific folders. This is:

Main directory ~Project
Code ~Project\Code

Within my setup chunk I declare:

```
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = "~Project")
knitr::opts_knit$get("root.dir")
```

However, in any following chunk where, for example I wish to load a dataset stored in 'Data' folder as:

```
read.csv("Data/series.csv",header=TRUE,check.names=FALSE)
```

I get a warning message on failure to find such directory.

Any advice? Thank you very much!

Comment: Rmd file is located within the 'Code' sub-directory

Comment: Yes, so ... `"../Data/series.csv"`? While it might help us to have a more complete minimal working example here, it might help you more to just add `getwd()` early in your document and render it (errors and all); I'm thinking that `getwd` will tell you that the process is not where you expect it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a ".." before that to tell R Studio first to go up a level (to the main directory):

```
read.csv("../Data/series.csv",header=TRUE,check.names=FALSE)
```

If you want to check what directory you're in, try running code like `print(getwd())` in your chunk.

It's also not clear whether your error comes when you try to knit the document, or just when working on the Project; that does make a difference.

Comment: Hi! Problem arised both when running all chunks and when running the specific command line.
This is my settings chunk:
`knitr::opts_knit$set(echo = FALSE, eval=TRUE, warning=FALSE)
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir ="E:/Lecture 1/Research Project/")
knitr::opts_knit$get("root.dir")` \\
In the following chunk I found these commands useful:
# 1 
`data<-read.csv(paste(knitr::opts_knit$get("root.dir"),"/Data/series.csv",
                     sep=""),
               header=TRUE,check.names=FALSE)` 
# 2 
`data<-read.csv("../Data/series.csv",header=TRUE,check.names=FALSE)`
Thanks!